# How can i make a strip inside an oval in css (partially filled vertical vessel effect)?

Tags: css

I have an oval and inside i want to include an strip to make a level of liquid volume.

I made this:

```
    <style scoped>
.strip:before {
  position: absolute;
  background: #343434;
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 15%;
  left: 0;
}

.oval div {
  position: absolute;
  background: #343434;
  background-repeat: repeat;
  border-width: thin 10px;
  transition: all;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 50% / 0 100%;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 50% / 0 100%;
  border-radius: 150px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 80%;
}
</style>
```

The result of that is this:
[image]

What I want to do is that the green part is a strip to change its value depending on the level of liquid.

The bottom value, it could be a value that constantly changes.

**--EDIT**
 I have it like that

```
<div class="oval" >
            <div class="strip" v-bind:style="{ background: props.item.color}"></div>
          </div>
```

Comment: can you explain what are you expecting result?\

Comment: @Kumar I'm expecting chage the value of the strip, increasing its value or decreasing its value

Comment: Is this HTML? If so, what is v-bind:

Comment: @JamesDouglas oh, is Vue.js the background value changes depending of the liquid, there are green, black or red, i obtain the HEX color from my database :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want an effect of a "partially filled" bar, then you can achieve this with a single `div` using `linear-gradient` background:

```css
.oval {
  --fill-level: 60%;

  background: linear-gradient(0deg, green var(--fill-level), black var(--fill-level));
  border-width: thin 10px;
  border-radius: 150px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 80%;
}
```

```html
<div class="oval"></div>
```

And if you change `0deg` to `90deg`, you'll get the classic horizontal "progress bar":

```css
.oval {
  --fill-level: 60%;

  background: linear-gradient(90deg, green var(--fill-level), black var(--fill-level));
  border-width: thin 10px;
  border-radius: 150px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 80%;
}
```

```html
<div class="oval"></div>
```

Comment: the last color should always start at 0% or you will see the blur

Comment: @Paulie_D, a great idea, thank you for the hint. Edited.

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there. You can do this with a single element: `.oval`. With the oval rendered you can target the `:before` pseudo selector and add your line and control the line's `bottom` value.

```css
.oval {
  position: absolute;
  background: #343434;
  background-repeat: repeat;
  border-width: thin 10px;
  transition: all;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 50% / 0 100%;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 50% / 0 100%;
  border-radius: 150px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 80%;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: green;
}
.oval:before {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 25%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 3px;
  background: black;
  content: '';
}
```

```html
<div class="oval"></div>
```

Or you can do it with a separate element like you're attempting to do in your example. Instead of trying to render the line with `:before` on the `.strip` element make `.strip` a child of your oval. If done this way you wont need the `:before` selector on your `.strip` element.

```css
.strip {
  position: absolute;
  background: #343434;
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
  z-index: 1;
  bottom: 25%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 3px;
}

.oval {
  position: absolute;
  background: #343434;
  background-repeat: repeat;
  border-width: thin 10px;
  transition: all;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 50% / 0 100%;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 50% / 0 100%;
  border-radius: 150px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 80%;
  background-color: green;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="oval">
  <div class="strip"></div>
</div>
```